# Stacking Arrays in pylab using vstack

Tags: python, ipython

I have to following code to stack arrays and solve a system of equations:

```
 1     import numpy as np
 2     from numpy.linalg import solve

 3     xi = np.array([-1., 1., -2])
 4     yi = np.array([0., 4., 3.])
 5     A = np.vstack([np.ones(3), xi, xi**2]).T
 6     b = yi

 7     c = solve(A,b)
```

Then After this I have code to execute a graph, But I get an error on the line 5. It says:

```
  TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That's a very funny error.  Are you sure you're not getting an `AttributeError`?  (no attribute `T`)

Comment: @mgilson I've gotten about just every other error. But the transpose seems to be fine

Comment: You're trying to transpose a list which isn't going to work.

Comment: It should be transposing a stack of numpy arrays

Comment: Now it is since you've added the parenthsis back in there.  Are you sure the error says `__get_item__` instead of `__getitem__`?  Can you copy/past the traceback?

Comment: You're right. My bad, I can't copy and paste from my virtual machine for some reason

Comment: Are you sure that's your actual code?  I copy-pasted the relevant bits and python didn't raise any errors for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've got your brackets confused. The code as printed above has mismatched brackets at line 5: `([...)]` so it gives a SyntaxError. I'd guess that the version you actually used was `[(...)]` which gives the error you report. The problem is that you're trying to call a function using square brackets, when python syntax requires round ones. Try putting the brackets the other way round: `([...])` The code then runs fine on my system.

EDIT: The question was edited while I typed this, so ignore the first two sentences. I still suspect that the ordering of the brackets was wrong in the code actually run.